# How a Page View Controller can pause the Root View Controller from running. (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

My app starts with a ***View Controller (Initial)***. On this View Controller i display a countdown message (using ***NSTimer*** and ***scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval***) that is auto-initiated when the user opens the app (***viewDidLoad method***).
In the settings menu (a second View Controller (**modal segue** to the initial) a have a "Tutorial" menu choice that leads to a ***Page View Controller*** that handles a couple of ***View Controllers*** and presents them as Form Sheets). The last page of ***this Page View Controller*** has a button "OK" that dismisses the ***Page View Controller*** (so that brings you back to the Settings menu according to my ***Storyboard***).

So far, so good.

Now when the user runs the app, i call from my ***initial View Controller*** the ***viewDidAppear*** method and using ***NSUserDefaults*** i run a check if this is the first time the user runs the app. If YES it creates an instance of the ***Page View Controller*** that displays (as form sheet) the Tutorial. And here is my problem..The ***initial View Controller*** is running at the background as expected to do so.. but how can i pause the countdown message until the user dismisses the Tutorial (by pressing the OK button)?

> NOTICE: I've just noticed that if you change the page view controller
>   presentation as "Full Screen" or run the app on the iphone instead of
>   the ipad (forced full screen presentation) the app is running normally, but that,i
>   assume, is because in this case (full screen presentation) the initial
>   view controller won't load until the page view controller is being
>   dismissed!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your PageViewController has a reference to his parent view controller (InitialViewController), so you have to define your NSTimer as a InitialViewController **property**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global app notification system to let know your `rootViewController` about external events. Check out `NSNotificationCenter` class reference.